# What does the luck stat do in Warhammer: End Times - Vermintide?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide

In Vermintide, it's possible to acquire a trinket which increases your luck. The trinket reads:

> While equipped, your luck is increased by *x*%

<sub>(Where *x* is the value)</sub>

What exactly does increased luck amount to? Reading around, there appear to be two theories:

- Increased chances of finding loot / loot die in a chest
- Increased proc chance of items

I play with a friend who has the trinket, and we allow her to open all the chests but I don't really notice any extra in chests (stuff seems to appear around 50% of the time) when she opens chests, vs when I open chests with / without her; however, I do feel like perhaps my item (which has a 8% chance proc) procs more often when she's in the party, but I can't be certain.

What does luck do?

Answer (score 4):

I can't confirm one way or another, nor do I have an official source; however, the [Wiki suggests](http://vermintide.gamepedia.com/Loot_Die) that trinkets which increase the luck stat increase the probability of finding *Loot Die* when *that* player opens the chest:

> Trinkets which increase "luck" will increase the probability of finding a Loot Die when the player wearing the trinket opens a loot chest.

[The Wiki](http://vermintide.gamepedia.com/Luckstone) also goes on to mention that the *Luckstone* trinket increases luck, which is the chance a *Loot Die* will be found when opening a chest:

> The Luckstone increases luck, which is the chance that a Loot Die will be found when opening a loot chest.

Comment: I equipped my 50% luck trinket and I've found this to be true. I've found at least 1 loot die on Black Powder across 10+ games for each game. Sometimes I've even gotten 2 loot die. There are a decent amount of chests on this small map, making it easy to test and worthwhile.